# Using "path" and "asset" for non-template data

Tags: path, symfony, assets

When creating templates with Twig, it's easy to use the `path` and `asset` functions.

```
<a href="{{ path('my_route') }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/my_image.png') }}" /></a>
```

However, some of my data come from non-twig files or from database. What would be the right way to address these functions from there?

So far, I'm using regex replace (`preg_replace_callback`) for the path function. But isn't there a nicer way?

Comment: Nothing keeps you from writing a custom function that returns the respective path to your file.

Comment: @Яaffael1984: I'm not sure if I made my question clear - some text comes from txt/html files or database string/text fields. I'm looking for a way to parse these files - that is to add the correct path where required - that could be considered a correct symfony2 approach.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. The best bet would probably be to create a couple of Twig extensions. I'll try to whip something up tomorrow.

Comment: @gilden: What do you have in mind? Something like `{{ content|parseExt }}`? That's definitely possible, my question only is if this is the "nice" way to go. I'm sure I'm not the first one with this problem.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the idea, but instead of a filter I guess it would be nicer to use a function: `{{ file('@AcmeDemoBundle:Foo:index.txt') }}`. This file would be at /src/Acme/Bundle/DemoBundle/Foo/index.txt and the function would print the contents to the template. Most elegant solution in Symfony2 I could imagine :)

Comment: @Czechnology I have finished making a working prototype. It will now take some time to set up a public repository on GitHub. Since this is my first, I'm not sure how long it'll take.

Answer (score 3):

I am proud to present my first public mini-project, the [StaticBundle](https://github.com/kgilden/KGStaticBundle). It pretty much lets you include any file in a bundle straight into a template.

### Setup

**EDIT** The bundle can now be installed using composer, please see the instructions on [readme](https://github.com/kgilden/KGStaticBundle/blob/master/README.md#installation).

Add the following to `deps`:

```
[KGStaticBundle]
    git=git://github.com/kgilden/KGStaticBundle.git
    target=bundles/KG/StaticBundle
```

Run `bin/vendors install`.

Register the namespace in `app/autoload.php`:

```
'KG' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
```

Register the bundle in `app/AppKernel.php`:

```
new KG\StaticBundle\KGStaticBUndle(),
```

### Basic usage

Suppose we have a file `src/Acme/Bundle/DemoBundle/Static/hello.txt` ready to be included in a template. We'd have to use a `file` function:

```
{# src/Acme/Bundle/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/index.html.twig #}

{{ file('@AcmeDemoBundle/Static/hello.txt') }}
```

The logical name gets resolved into the actual path and a simple `file_get_contents` retrieves the data.

Comment: Nice. It may be useful to add an `asset_contents` function the same way.

Comment: How is this loaded using composer.json ?

Comment: @JakeN just updated the bundle, so `composer require kgilden/static-bundle` should do the trick.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks, I will give it a go this week.