# Including a non-twig file from twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to include the contents of a file (inside my resources folder) inside a Twig template.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
{% include 'public/directory/file.ext' %}
```

Isn't Twig capable of this? (I don't want to use Assetic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a [bundle](https://github.com/kgilden/KGStaticBundle) just for this some time ago. It's pretty much a wrapper for `file_get_contents`.

The setup can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555422/using-path-and-asset-for-non-template-data/7576081#7576081).

Comment: Making a Twig Extension is the way to go. I have implemented one based on your bundle, but if someone has no time or knowdledge for doing this, your bundle is a nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: Just an improvement for your extension: when you call "file" from the template, you will notice that the output is escaped (if you have autoescape on), so you will be forced to add the "raw" filter. In order to avoid that, add this as the third parameter of your Twig_Function_Method call: array('is_safe' => array('html'))

Comment: @gilden where is the composer.json in your repo?

Answer (score 17):

> New in version 1.15: The source function was added in Twig 1.15.
>   The source function returns the content of a template without rendering it

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/source.html

Comment: This only works if you're reading a template. This does not allow to include arbitrary files.

Answer (score 1):

Twig will complain when loading your file if it is not a valid twig template. The reason is that Twig will include the rendered file and not the content of it (found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates)).

You could try with a `use` statement but I don't think this will work either.

Moreover, the syntax you use seems incorrect. When I include (or use) another twig template, I use this syntax:

```
{% use "AcmeWebsiteBundle::include.html.twig" %}
```

And the file `include.html.twig` resideds in `src\Acme\WebsiteBundle\Resources\views\include.html.twig`. So, if your file is in `src\Acme\WebsiteBundle\Resources\public\directory\include.ext`, you could try

```
{% use "AcmeWebsiteBundle::..\public\directory\include.ext" %}
```

If that doesn't work, you could possibly move the file into the views folder. If this is not possible, you can possibliy put in `app\Resources\views\` and use the syntax:

```
{% use "::include.ext" %}
```

If the use statement doesn't work, which I'm afraid of, you could possibly wrap your file into a twig template directly. I'm templating some simple JSON structures with twig. So, there may be a way for you to include the content of `file.ext` into a twig template and then render it.

If all this fail, you will have to create a Twig extension that add a new tag (something like `content`) that would read a file and output its content in your twig template.

```
{% content 'public/directory/file.ext' %} {# would put content of the file #}
```

Hope this will help you to include your file.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but your suggestions don't work. Please, if you answer, at least you should be sure that what you suggest works.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with twig extension functions. ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html )

Create a php file in your Bundle for the Twig extension

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_SimpleFunction;

class AppExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
  public function getFunctions()
  {
    return array(
      new Twig_SimpleFunction('fileGetContents', array($this, 'fileGetContents') ),
    );
  }

  public function fileGetContents($file)
  {
    return file_get_contents($file);
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'app_extension';
  }
}
?>
```

Add this code to the app/config/services.yml

```
app.twig_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now you can use your custom function as any default function in your twig template

```
<p>{{ fileGetContents( asset("uploads/my_text_file.txt") ) }}</p>
```